# Laravel Echo not recognizing event

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have Laravel Echo set up successfully to listen to one event. However, when I tried to add an additional event to the same channel the first one was a part of, the client-side seemingly does not recognize this new event. However, looking at Laravel Horizon, I can see the jobs being registered and processed successfully. Any ideas on why this may be occurring?

**Code for non-working event:**

```
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class ParticipantCreated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $data;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->$data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('channelReceiveLiveData');
    }
}
```

**Code for Working event:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class liveDataTrigger implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('channelReceiveLiveData');
    }
}
```

**Controller where event is being emitted:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Participant;
use App\Test;
use App\Events\ParticipantCreated;

class ParticipantController extends Controller
{

    public function create() {
        event(new ParticipantCreated('test'));
    }
}
```

**VueJS component where Echo is setup:**

```
    // This one works
    Echo.channel('channelReceiveLiveData')
    .listen('liveDataTrigger', (e) => {
        console.log('Received Live Event');
    })

    // This one does not work
    .listen('ParticipantCreated', (e) => {
        console.log('Received Participant Created');
    });
```

**Bootstrap.js with laravel echo initialization**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.io = require('socket.io-client');


window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
});
```

I decided to try firing both events from the ParticipantController, and I get this output:

**laravel-echo-server console output:**

```
CHANNEL channelReceiveLiveData
Channel: channelReceiveLiveData
Event: App\Events\liveDataTrigger
CHANNEL channelReceiveLiveData
Channel: channelReceiveLiveData
Event: App\Events\ParticipantCreated
```

Comment: How are you publishing the events? Through Pusher or some socket.io stuff? Maybe check if this service actually publishes the event.

Comment: I am using Laravel-echo-server + Redis, and laravel-echo-server logs as well as laravel horizon indicate that the requests seem to be going through (according to console logs)

Answer (score 1):

When you are listening for events on a private channel, you need to tell `Echo` to do so by swapping `channel()` with `private()`:

```
Echo.private('channelReceiveLiveData')
    .listen('ParticipantCreated', (e) => {
        console.log('Received Participant Created');
    });
```

I guess this is because for a private channel, the laravel-echo-server needs to perform authentication towards your Laravel application. So make sure you followed all steps of installing the laravel-echo-server, including setting up your `pusher` configuration in `config/broadcasting.php`. Do not forget to configure `host` and `port` like so:

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
    'secret' => null,
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 6001,
    ],
],
```

Comment: The private channel was an accident, actually -- I decided to remove this and updated my post, and I still have the same issue :-(

Comment: Oh, ok, didn't see the update. Can you add the code of your other event to the question as well?

Comment: Sure thing, added above!

Comment: Hm, I can only spot two differences so far. 1) One of your events is written capitalized, the other not - I only used capitalized ones, so when the camel case one works, it seems to not matter. 2) The order of your `Echo.listen()` statements... maybe try to switch them, for debugging purposes. All of the other code looks pretty much the exact same than what I am using.. so I run out of ideas.

Comment: I tried modifying the camelCase, and that didn't seem to make a difference... and I switched the order, and also tried creating a new channel for the second event. I have no idea why it isn't working...

Comment: In laravel-echo-server you should see with what prefix the event is published (`App.Events.` normally). Is that the case for both of them?

Comment: It appears to be App.Events -- added console output to post above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172351/discussion-between-namoshek-and-mdobrenko).